# TP-Link Wireless Adapter not seeing any networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

About a year ago I installed this wireless adapter on my desktop PC to try to improve my performance on WiFi:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B4VH4G1C/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B4VH4G1C)

It seemed to work pretty well, but I recently moved to a new house and the adapter can no longer detect any networks ("No Wi-Fi networks found"). When I switched to the wireless adapter that came built into the computer (Realtek 8821CE wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC) I can see the networks just fine.

When I check the adapter's properties in the device manager, it says that "The device is working properly." I tried tried uninstalling and reinstalling the device drivers. I also tried removing the card physically from the PCI port (although I didn't disconnect the smaller cable, since I didn't want to risk breaking the connector).

I'm trying to figure out if maybe the device was physically damaged in the move, or maybe it's an issue with the router at the new house. Any advice on how to find out?

Comment: Just to check if your phone has built-in hotspot, have you tried enabling that and testing if that can get detected or not? That may rule out router issues in case.